# How can i solve Nuxt.js cannot find module '@vue/composition-api' error?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, vue-composition-api

When developing Nuxt.js

```
cannot find module '@ vue / composition-api
```

I get an error. Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stop the project and

```
# if you use yarn
$ yarn add @vue/composition-api

# if you use npm
$ npm install @vue/composition-api --save
```

download composition-api in your project.
And start again.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out this error is being caused by Vuter extension. This extension is requiring composition API which is available on Vue 3.x Disabling it fixes the problem but again you need Vuter yikes!

Answer (score -1):

Vue composition API is a latest feature presented onwards in Vuejs 3.0. Please make sure your base dependency is set to correct vuejs version in package.json file.

P.S I am not sure of Nuxt compatibility.

Comment: Described package works with Vue2 and it is community package. Check [this](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) for more info.